# How do I get my docker container onto hub.docker.com?

Tags: dockerhub

I am following this tutorial [Getting Started with Docker for the Node.js Developer](https://www.airpair.com/node.js/posts/getting-started-with-docker-for-the-nodejs-dev) and everything was working smoothly until I got to the end of tutorial where one is to execute these commands ...

```
$ docker tag node-express your_docker_hub_username/node-express  
$ docker rmi node-express  
$ docker push your_docker_hub_username/node-express
```

So for my system I did this ...

```
$ sudo docker ps -a | grep centos
1c912e61636d        node-express-centos:latest   "/bin/bash"            31 minutes ago      Exited (130) 28 minutes ago                       gloomy_mestorf
$ sudo docker tag node-express-centos redcricket/node-express-centos
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: could not find image: no such id: node-express-centos
$ sudo docker tag node-express-centos:latest redcricket/node-express-centos
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: could not find image: no such id: node-express-centos:latest
```

... and as you can see I am getting these FATA errors.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your container, you need to name it in order to be able to reference it by name. If not, you will have to reference it using the container ID.

To name your container you can do

`$ docker run - - name node-express-centos node-express-centos:latest`

You can then tag using same command you used above.